# Ruby Time object converted from float doesn't equal to orignial Time object

Tags: ruby, time, comparison

```
time = Time.now
fvalue = time.to_f
return time == Time.at(fvalue)
```

Can somebody here explain why the above expression returns false. How can I create a new Time object from float that matches the original time variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[IEEE 754 double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) (which is returned by `to_f`) is not accurate enough to represent the *exact* time.

```
t1 = Time.now
f1 = t1.to_f
t2 = Time.at(f1)

# they look the same
t1.inspect #=> '2013-09-09 23:46:08 +0200'
t2.inspect #=> '2013-09-09 23:46:08 +0200'

# but double does not have enough precision to be accurate to the nanosecond
t1.nsec #=> 827938306
t2.nsec #=> 827938318
#                  ^^

# so they are different
t1 == t2 #=> false
```

Do the following, to preserve the exact time:

```
t1 = Time.now
r1 = t1.to_r # value of time as a rational number
t2 = Time.at(r1)
t1 == t2 #=> true
```

Citation from [`Time.to_r`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-to_r):

> This methods is intended to be used to get an accurate value
>   representing the nanoseconds since the Epoch. You can use this method
>   to convert time to another Epoch.

Comment: I found something strange. Seems that to_r does not reflect nsec exactly. Date.today.end_of_day.to_r == (Date.today + 1.day).beginning_of_day.to_r  => true  ;  Date.today.end_of_day.nsec => 999999999; (Date.today + 1.day).beginning_of_day.nsec => 0.